# Narrowing possible parameter datatype for method call (for strings)

Tags: php, variables

If i wanted a function to exclusively expect an array, i'd write:

```
function _setIt(array $param){}
```

However, i have a case in which i expect a string.

Obviously i could run checks in the first line of my function.

But i want to know:
**Is there a way to use the above function declaration method to allow only strings to be passed to this function?**

I do expect it to be a problem because of the non-strict way PHP handles datatypes, but perhaps there is a way?

Of course

```
function _setIt(string $param){}
```

won't get me anywhere as `string` is interpreted as a possible class name.

Comment: From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):  `Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string. Resources and Traits are not allowed either.`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Are there any possible workarounds then, using a custom class perhaps? In any case please post your response as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as @AmalMurali pointed out.  However, [scalar typehints are under discussion](https://sheriframadan.com/2012/10/test-drive-php-5-5-a-sneak-peek/#scalartypehint) for a future version.

Use a class to represent your string data, and pass the object.  A __toString() method on that class will reasonably approximate a scalar string.

```
class StringString {
    public function __construct($string) {
        if (! is_string($string)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Not a string');
        }
        $this->string = $string;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->string;
    }
    private $string;
}

function myFunction(StrictString $s) {
    // no need to do is_string() here -- constructor does it
    // so one place, always checked, type hinting used elsewhere
    echo strlen($s); // guaranteed to be a string
}

$s = new StrictString('hello');
myFunction($s);
```

Finally, one important note: you don't need to write your own String class.  SPL already provides [SplString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splstring.php) whose stated intent is to "enforce strong typing of the string type".  Use that to get what you need for strings.  Use the pattern above or other types that don't have an SPL representation.

Comment: That is an interesting approach, but how can i use that custom class in a way that the type hinting (using that class) will cause an error if the data passed is not matching the conditions?

Comment: But once again setting data in `own class` should call for checking if string is passed to set method of a `own class`.

Comment: `function printStr(MyOwnStringClass $string)`

Comment: I don't think __toString will apply at all during type hinting. Isn't type hinting itself a form of abstract access to a classes properties?

Comment: @SquareCat: Refer to edit for example in answer to your questions.

Comment: The constructor is not called during type hinting, therefore this solution is not applicable. It seems there is no way to do this, other than to run datatype checks within the function itself. I'll accept your answer as solution because you clearly stated that its not possible and provided an informative link about possible usage of this method in the future. Thanks.

Comment: The state of PHP today: You can either do scalar type checks (a) in the function bodies or (b) in the class constructor of a "string" class and use class type hinting to enforce that "string".  IMO, choice b is usually better because the requirements of the type are defined in one spot (the constructor) and typehinting clearly states what type is per function expected.  But this adds a lot of glue and possibily performance issues, so it's not a one-size-fits-all solution. Hell, if you have the discipline to use the loose typing consistently, go for it!

Comment: I forgot one important pont about strings.  Refer to my edit regarding [SplString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splstring.php)

Answer (score 0):

Type hints cannot be used with scalar type values;

Throw exceptions instead

```
function _setIt($value) {

    if (!is_string($value)) {

         throw new Exception('Can only except a string');
    }
}
```

Another way that may be plausible dependant on use case is below;

```
function _setIt($value) {

    if (!is_string($value)) {

         settype($value, 'string');

         // Perform validity of string
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read me question. I clearly said that i am not looking for a solution that involves performing any checks within the function. It is an obvious solution but not what i am looking for.

Comment: That being said anyone else stumbling across this question would still want the correct solution showing to avoid ambiguity. This is the correct and only way to check for string data types in PHP.

Comment: +1 @SquareCat There isn't away, so this question is the answer

Comment: Actually, it might be better to use `gettype` instead: `if (gettype($param) == 'string') {`.

Comment: Good hints. Thanks. But it is not the correct answer because in my question i stated the obvious (which is what 'Help' and 'AlexP' kindly provided for other people who might seek a solution to this problem)  and that i do not look for such an approach. Either YES and HOW, or NO and WHY NOT does suffice.

Comment: I updated to the only other plausible solution I could think of, hope you get everything working.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been said, you cannot type hint on scalar types (like you can with class names or interfaces).

You **will need to explicitly check** that the value is a string

```
function foo($argument) {
  if (! is_string($argument)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentExecption('The argument is not a string');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my question i already clarified that doing a check within the function is an option but this is not what my question was about.